I need the cut of these three faces to be even, into 3 equal parts of the type. I do not know how to explain
I need the cut of these three faces to be even, into 3 equal parts of the type. I do not know how to explain

Use this.

https://neroduck.ru/screens/blender_GMUyRk-27-10-2024.png @Leander
I select 3 faces, right click, loop tools, space.

Only select the top and bottom horizontal edge loop. Don't select the vertical edges.
